# Unable to show a network image in a Built Flutter web app

Tags: flutter

My images are all hosted in AliCloud, I can show the image successfully in local developing mode, but failed to display the image in a web build.

Here is the image link and the code:

https://chilleasy-image.oss-cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/prod/img/24/badabcd5a5df790bd70daed4e7db15fe.jpg

```
Container(
  child: Image.network(
            ImageList[index].image_path,
            fit: BoxFit.contain),
),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use html renderer:

```
flutter build web --release --web-renderer html
```

or

```
flutter run --web-renderer html
```